# insert strmacro instead of function in ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I wrote a strmacro function in R and now I want to do this strmacro on an array of string. Thus, I tried to use ddply and to insert strmacro function instead of regular function but I didn't succeed.
I would like you to help me.

thanks,
Amit

Comment: Please give us some more detail on what you have tried and make a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem is, but here is a working example with `strmacro` and `ddply`:

```
# example from ?strmacro
setNA <- strmacro(df, var, values,
                  expr={
                    df$var[df$var %in% values] <- NA
                  })
# create example data using 999 as a missing value indicator
d <- data.frame(
  Grp=c("Trt", "Ctl", "Ctl", "Trt", "Ctl", "Ctl", "Trt", "Ctl", "Trt", "Ctl"),
  V1=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 999, 8,   9,  10),
  V2=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 999, 2, 999, 999)
)
# ddply call
ddply(d, .(Grp), function(x){
  setNA(x, V1, 999)
  x
  })
```